# How to provision Docker images in Vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, docker, vagrantfile, boot2docker

**UPDATE**
I found the solution myself - I created a simple boilerplate here: https://github.com/ezmilhouse/docker
Feel free to go on from here.

the Dockerfile in my `build_dir` needs various docker images to be available (already built), I thought I could force Vagrant to build those images as part of the provision process - this didn't work out.

```rb
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.define "app" do |app|

    # provision
    app.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
      d.build_image "/Docker/lib/ubuntu", args: "-t local/ubuntu"
      d.build_image "/Docker/lib/ubuntu-mongodb", args: "-t local/ubuntu-mongodb"
      d.build_image "/Docker/lib/ubuntu-nginx-vagrant", args: "-t local/ubuntu-nginx"
      d.build_image "/Docker/lib/ubuntu-node", args: "-t local/ubuntu-node"
    end

    # provider
    app.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
      d.build_dir = "."
    end

  end

end
```

How can I make sure that all of my docker images are built, when the provider takes over?

Comment: are your starting up your vm with `vagrant up --provision`?

Comment: yes, vagrant up --provision --provider=docker

Comment: Can you share the Dockerfile which is used for the Vagrant docker provider and explain where the "/Docker/lib/" directories are?